# Using template to generate a static lookup table

Tags: c++, templates

I have:

```
const char kLetters[] = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
```

I can call `kLetters[n]` to obtain the nth letter of the Keyboard alphabet in O(1) time. However I will have to iterate through kLetter (taking O(n) or at least O(log n) ) time for the reverse lookup.

I would like to create a reverse lookup table as a compile-time static lookup table using templates and was wondering if there is a ways of doing this.

EDIT - as mentioned in the comments, a reverse lookup would mean I supply 'E' and get back 2. Also my alphabet example was not the best example, I would like to make no assumptions about the order. For that reason I have change the alphabet to keyboard order.

Comment: `kLetters[n]` obtains `(n+1)th` letter.

Comment: What is `reverse lookup` by the way?

Comment: @Nawaz: Presumably, a function that given e.g.`'E'` returns `4`.

Comment: What about `'A' + n` and `letter - 'A'` for those lookups if you really want to look up English alphabet.

Comment: @Oli: thanks. That is very short, yet interesting comment :D

Comment: @UncleBens: That's definitely it. As long as your encoding guarantees that the letters are arranged contiguously (which is the case for ASCII and EBCDIC), this works and is efficient.

Comment: @UncleBens nice and simple solution given the example.

Comment: @Kerrek: No! It isn't the case for EBCDIC. There are two gaps in the alphabet in EBCDIC. EBCDIC is the classical example of why `'A' + n` is not portable.

Comment: @R. Martinho: Ohh, my bad! I thought because it was true for numerals it'd also be true for letters. Never mind then!

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes, does anybody even use EBCDIC anymore? And if so, do they use it in C++?

Comment: @Mark: I have no idea. It is rare to the point that I don't bother with it. Kerrek brought that up, I was only pointing out a mistake in his comment.

Comment: The only portable answer I can think of that handles the case where char is 64 bits and the letters are scattered at random in the character set far apart is a std::map.   :(

Answer (score 5):

How about something like this? It lets you specify the range rather than a complete string.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int Start, int End, int N>
struct lookup {
        static_assert(Start != End, "Can't have 0 length lookup table");
        enum { value =  lookup<Start+(Start < End ? 1:-1),End,N-1>::value };
};

template <int Start, int End>
struct lookup<Start,End,0> {
        enum { value = Start };
};

template <int Start, int End, int V, int P=0>
struct reverse_lookup {
        static_assert(Start != End, "V isn't in the range Start, End");
        static_assert(Start != End || !P, "Can't have 0 length range");
        enum { value = reverse_lookup<Start+(Start < End ? 1:-1),End,V,P+1>::value };
};

template <int Start, int End, int P>
struct reverse_lookup<Start,End,Start,P> {
        enum { value = P };
};

int main() {
   std::cout << char(lookup<'A', 'Z', 3>::value) << std::endl;
   std::cout << char(lookup<'Z', 'A', 3>::value) << std::endl;
   std::cout << int(reverse_lookup<'A','Z','F'>::value) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If Oli's version of what reverse means is correct I'll update to add that.

Comment: Nice - I was going to accept the challenge and try something but looks like you beat me to it.

Comment: What if the letters are in arbitrary order? Like `"ZBADCEWFVGHIUXTKSLYQMROPN"`?

Comment: Also, this solution means user has to know the letter at compile-time for which index has to be obtained!

Comment: fast, but doesn't work for EBCDIC, and only works on compile-time constants.

Comment: I don't see the point here. Either the letters are sorted like in the question, then you can simply add `('A'-1)` for the lookup and subtract the same for the reverse lookup, otherwise, your approach doesn't work (because you use `+1` to iterate to the next value). Also you really have a problem if you want to lookup a variable (as opposed to your constant `3`).

Comment: @Nawaz: If letters are in arbitrary order your solution won't work either :)

Comment: @bitmask - I don't quite see the point either, but I was working on the assumption that the question was meant to be a simple example of a bigger problem.

Comment: @David: Yeah I know that. But I've come with a solution using template which would work with any arbitrary sequences of letters (I hope so). I've taken your help in that as well.

Comment: @David: See my solution. It has no restriction.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, after knowing what reverse lookup is, I think you can do this:

```
const char kLetters[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

int get_index(char letter)
{
     return letter - 'A';
}
```

After all, the letter `A` is at index `0`, `B` at `1`, `C` at `2`... and so on. That gives enough hint.

---

## My O(1) solution

.

So far other solutions work for *non-arbitrary* sequence of letters, and @awoodland solution assumes that the letter whose index is to be obtainted is **known at compile time** which makes it less useful.

But this solution has attempted to solve both limitations; that is, it should work:

- With arbitrary sequence of letters, such as

  ```
     const char Letters[] = "ZBADCEWFVGHIUXJTKSLYQMROPN";
  ```
- And the letters may be *unknown* at compile time. The function that gets the index has this signature:

  ```
  int Index(char letter);
  ```

Here is the complete code which uses a technique described by @ David Rodríguez in [his blog](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/dynamic-dispatching-of-template.html):

```
#include <iostream>

const char Letters[] = "ZBADCEWFVGHIUXJTKSLYQMROPN";

template<char L> int Index();

template<> int Index<'Z'>() { return 0; }
template<> int Index<'B'>() { return 1; }
template<> int Index<'A'>() { return 2; }
template<> int Index<'D'>() { return 3; }
template<> int Index<'C'>() { return 4; }
template<> int Index<'E'>() { return 5; }
template<> int Index<'W'>() { return 6; }
template<> int Index<'F'>() { return 7; }
template<> int Index<'V'>() { return 8; }
template<> int Index<'G'>() { return 9; }
template<> int Index<'H'>() { return 10; }
template<> int Index<'I'>() { return 11; }
template<> int Index<'U'>() { return 12; }
template<> int Index<'X'>() { return 13; }
template<> int Index<'J'>() { return 14; }
template<> int Index<'T'>() { return 15; }
template<> int Index<'K'>() { return 16; }
template<> int Index<'S'>() { return 17; }
template<> int Index<'L'>() { return 18; }
template<> int Index<'Y'>() { return 19; }
template<> int Index<'Q'>() { return 20; }
template<> int Index<'M'>() { return 21; }
template<> int Index<'R'>() { return 22; }
template<> int Index<'O'>() { return 23; }
template<> int Index<'P'>() { return 24; }
template<> int Index<'N'>() { return 25; }

typedef int (*fptr)();
const int limit = 26;
fptr indexLookup[ limit ];

template <char L>
struct init_indexLookup {
    static void init( fptr *indexLookup ) {
        indexLookup[ L - 'A' ] = &Index<L>;
        init_indexLookup<L-1>::init( indexLookup );
    }
};

template <>
struct init_indexLookup<'A'> {
    static void init( fptr *indexLookup ) {
        indexLookup[ 0 ] = &Index<'A'>;
    }
};

const int ignore = (init_indexLookup<'Z'>::init(indexLookup),0);

int Index(char letter)
{
    return indexLookup[letter-'A']();
}
```

And here is the test code:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << Index('A') << std::endl;
    std::cout << Index('Z') << std::endl;
    std::cout << Index('B') << std::endl;
    std::cout << Index('K') << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
2
0
1
16
```

Online demo : http://ideone.com/uzE2t

Well, that actually is two function calls: one to `Index()`, other to from one in the `indexLookup`. You can easily *avoid* first function call by writing ([ideone](http://ideone.com/zBtCE)):

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << indexLookup['A'-'A']() << std::endl;
    std::cout << indexLookup['Z'-'A']() << std::endl;
    std::cout << indexLookup['B'-'A']() << std::endl;
    std::cout << indexLookup['K'-'A']() << std::endl;
}
```

That looks cumbersome, but hey, we can make `Index()` inline:

```
inline int Index(char letter)
{
    return indexLookup[letter-'A']();
}
```

That looks fine, and most likely now compiler will make it equivalent to one function call!

---

## Simple yet O(1) solution

Wait. I just realized that the whole solution reduces to a lookup table which is initialized as:

```
 const int indexLookup[] = {2,1,4,3,5,7,9,10,11,14,16,18,21,
                            25,23,24,20,22,17,15,12,8,6,13,19,0};

 inline int Index(char letter)
 {
       return indexLookup[letter-'A'];
 }
```

which looks unbelievably simple!

Comment: ... so long as it remains that string in that encoding

Comment: @Mooing Duck: the code does not suppose characters are numbered contiguously, therefore should work with EBCDIC as well.

Comment: @Mooing: Now my template solution doesn't have that restriction, if at all it is.

Comment: @Mooing: You can easily avoid one function call. See my edit in the bottom. :-)

Comment: @Mooing: It just came to my mind, and I wrote that already in my answer.

Comment: @Nawaz: waitasec... `init_indexLookup::init` and `Index` both have `letter-'A', which assume all letters are within 25 of 'A', so it still fails with EBCDIC, doesn't it?

Comment: @Mooing: I don't know about `EBCDIC`. So cannot comment on it and don't know how to fix this either. But since its only about offset to the table, then I suppose that can be easily solved!

Comment: @Nawaz: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimal_Interchange_Code:    `'A'` is 193, `'Z'` is 233.

Comment: @Mooing: Is that unsolvable? If its unsolvable, then we've to make the `indexLookup` array as big as the value of `Z`. And all the entries before index `A` and few in between `A` and `Z`, will point to null. Not a big deal, I guess?

Comment: technically the indexLookup array has to be as big as the (value for the largest character) - (value for smallest character), but the C++ standard does not guarantee _any_ constraints on that range.  They could theoretically be any distance apart.

Comment: @Mooing: As `char` cannot be greater than `1` byte (that is guaranteed by the C++ Standard),  can the largest value be greater than `255`? If  yes, how exactly?

Comment: @Nawaz: There are modern systems in use where a byte is 64 bits.  Motorola's DSP56F805 has 16 bit chars.

Comment: @Mooing: Just have a look at my new solution. Its unbelievably simple. :|

Comment: @Nawaz: And fast!  ...but still crashes with non-sequential character sets.  Not that anyone uses them, I admit.

Comment: @Mooing: That is just offset/indexing problem; and I believe can be solved with some nice trick, without much overhead.

Comment: @Nawaz: The standard doesn't guarantee that 'Z' and 'A' are within 4x10^18 of each other.  And I don't have that much RAM.  Note that I'm observing limitations that my answer also runs into.

Comment: @Mooing: Don't worry, we can split the table into few tables; that is the easiest way to solve this.

Comment: @Nawaz: Instead of making things complicated, either (A) assume ASCII, or (B) use a std::map.

Comment: @Mooing: Even if it's `EBCDIC`, aren't the values of characters fixed? Like `A` is 193, `Z` is 233, etc. If so, then where did this figure `4x10^18` come from? With `EBCDIC`, an array of `'Z'` size should work.

Comment: @Nawaz: what about a character set that comes out five years from now?  Will that one also have 'Z' be small?

Comment: @Mooing: We will have different solution. Not every problem can be solved before the problem exists!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3457/discussion-between-mooing-duck-and-nawaz)

Comment: The problem with this solution (both of them is that I need two tables that effectively contain the same information. If I update the one and not the other, we have a mess.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Boost and only need compile-time lookups:

```
using namespace boost::mpl;
typedef vector_c<char, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'> Chars;   

// lookup by index:
std::cout << at_c<Chars, 1>::type::value << std::endl; // B 

// lookup by value:
typedef find<Chars, integral_c<char, 'C'> >::type Iter;
std::cout << Iter::pos::value << std::endl; // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that 'Z' > 'A', but does not assume letters are contiguous.  (Though it takes less memory if they are)  I was tempted to put in `if (numrLetters>26)` conditionals so a smart compiler could use addition rather than the tables for ASCII, but then decided I didn't want to slow the code in the case of less-smart compilers.

```
const char kLetters[] = "ABCDEFGHJJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const int numLetters = sizeof(kLetters);
const char rkLetters['Z'-'A'] = {};
const int numrLetters = sizeof(rkLetters);
struct LetterInit {
    LetterInit() {
        for(int i=0; i<numLetters; ++i)
            rkLetters[kLetters[i]-'A'] = i;
    }
}LetterInitInst;

char findChar(int index) {
    assert(index>=0 && index<numLetters);
    return kLetters[index];
}
int findIndex(char letter) { 
    assert(letter>='A' && letter<='Z');
    return rkLetters[letter-'A'];
}
```

Comment: _If_ Z and A are far apart, the table can be large, but I know of no system where this is the case.

Comment: This does runtime initialization, what I am really after is Compile time initialization where the reverse array is loaded as const static data.

Answer (score 0):

As there are several solutions given that don't generate a table but still allow compile time lookup, here is another one

```
constexpr char kLetters[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
constexpr int get(char const x, int const i = 0) {
  return kLetters[i] == x ? i : get(x, i + 1);
}
```

Use at compile time

```
int x[get('F')];
static_assert(sizeof(x) == sizeof(int[5]), "");
```

Specifying a character that doesn't exist will result in an error. If you use the function at runtime, you will get undefined behavior if you specify a character that doesn't exist. Proper checking can be added for those cases.

It yields the index of the first character found. No error is given if a character appears twice in the haystack.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use c++0x (tested with gcc 4.5), this works:

```
#include<initializer_list>
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
constexpr int getLetterNumber(char a){ return std::map<char,int>({{'a',2},{'b',1},{'c',4}})[a]; }
int main(){
    const char ch='b';
    std::cout<<ch<<": "<<getLetterNumber(ch)<<std::endl;
}
```

`constexpr` enforces evaluation at compile-time.

**EDIT**: that solution is not correct, as pointed out. `constexpr` does not enfoce compile-time evaluation. This does does the lookup really at compile-time (similar to solutions posted meanwhile).

```
#include<iostream>
template<char C> int ch2Num();
#define CHR(c,i) template<> int ch2Num<c>(){ return i; }
CHR('a',2); CHR('b',1); /* ... */
#undef CHR
int main(void){
    const char ch='b';
    std::cout<<ch<<": "<<ch2Num<ch>()<<std::endl;
};
```

Comment: No, `constexpr` does not *enforce* evaluation at compile-time. It *allows* it. That nitpick aside, *this code should not even compile*. `std::map` does not have any `constexpr` constructor.

Comment: Just checked the disassembly, you're right. The function is called (or inlined with `-O3`, even if `ch` and the number are made `constexpr` as well :-(.